# Use induction to prove that when $n≥1$, $a_i\in R$, $a_i > 0$, if $a_1a_2...a_n=1$, then $(1+a_1)(1+a_2)...(1+a_n)≥2^n$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, induction

Use induction to prove that when $n≥1$, $a_i\in R$, $a_i > 0$, if $a_1a_2\cdots a_n=1$, then $(1+a_1)(1+a_2)\cdots(1+a_n)≥2^n$.*

The base case is simple, but I do not know how to complete the inductive step:

If $a_1a_2\cdots a_{n+1}=1$, then $(1+a_1)(1+a_2)\cdots(1+a_{n+1})≥2^{n+1}$.

I made a case when $a_{n+1}=1$, but could not complete the other cases.

There are other proofs of this inequality, but I do not think they use the "if" part require in this proof.

*Another way to write this inequality is as follows:
$$
\left(\frac{1+a_1}{2}\right)\cdots \left(\frac{1+a_n}{2}\right) \ge 1
.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use AM-GM, then $$1+a_1\geq2\sqrt{a_1}$$ and $$1+a_2\geq 2\sqrt{a_2}$$ … and $$1+a_n\geq 2\sqrt{a_n}$$ so §$$(1+a_1)(1+a_2)\cdot ...\cdot(1+a_n)\geq  2^n\sqrt{a_1\cdot a_2\cdots a_n}=2^n$$

Answer (score 2):

One of the $a_i$ is $\ge1$ and one is $\le 1$. Say $a_n\ge1\ge a_{n+1}$.
Then
$$(1+a_n)(1+a_{n+1})-2(1+a_na_{n+1})=(a_n-1)(1-a_{n+1})\ge0.$$
Then
$$(1+a_1)\cdots(1+a_{n+1})\ge2(1+a_1)\cdots(1+a_{n-1})(1+a_na_{n+1})$$
and now apply the inductive hypothesis.

Comment: $$(1+a_1)\cdots(1+a_{n+1})\ge2(1+a_1)\cdots(1+a_{n-1})(1+a_na_{n+1})$$
What is in the second "..."? Or what is this called?

Comment: A $\cdots$ is called an *ellipsis*. I'm using it in the same way as you did, omitting intermediate factors.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask what were those factors. I do not understand the factorization. The second question was if this factorization had some name.

Comment: I just understood what you did. I thought you carried out some similar factorization on the entire RHS of the last inequality. Thanks.

Comment: Could I ask, how did you come up with this substitution? Did you work backwards, starting with the idea of using the IH on n elements (considering the n+1 terms as n terms by combining the last two), then multiplying the IH inequality by 2, then proving that this 'side' of the inequality is less than the original (n+1)-termed one?